# What is the equivalent of TimingLogger in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, profiling

```
        val timings = TimingLogger("FEED_PROFILE", "reading bitmap frame")
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.size);
        timings.addSplit("converting bytes to bitmap done")
        val bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.width, bitmap.height, bitmap.config)
        timings.addSplit("reading bitmap done")
        timings.dumpToLog()
```

The above prints

```
D/FEED_PROFILE( 5019): reading bitmap frame: begin
D/FEED_PROFILE( 5019): reading bitmap frame:      244 ms, converting bytes to bitmap done
D/FEED_PROFILE( 5019): reading bitmap frame:      0 ms, reading bitmap done
D/FEED_PROFILE( 5019): reading bitmap frame: end, 244 ms
```

But this is Kotlin/Java code. What does Flutter/Dart have to achieve similar result ?

Currently, I am using

```
 final start = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
 // something
 final lapse = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - start;
 print('$logId Screenshoot took $lapse ms ${pngBytes.length}');
```

But this gets complicates when I try to replicate the `addSplit` . Hence I am looking for something built-in in either Dart or Flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a plugin while waiting for an answer https://pub.dev/packages/timing_logger